# Pandas: Timeseries data: How to select rows of an hour or a day or a minute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have huge time series dataset in a .csv file. There are two columns in the file:

1. `values`: These are sample values.
2. `dttm_utc`: These are the timestamps when the samples are collected.

I've imported the data into pandas using `pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=["dttm_utc"])`. When I print the first 50 rows of `dttm_utc` column, they looks like this:

```
0    2012-01-01 00:05:00
1    2012-01-01 00:10:00
2    2012-01-01 00:15:00
3    2012-01-01 00:20:00
4    2012-01-01 00:25:00
5    2012-01-01 00:30:00
6    2012-01-01 00:35:00
7    2012-01-01 00:40:00
8    2012-01-01 00:45:00
9    2012-01-01 00:50:00
10   2012-01-01 00:55:00
11   2012-01-01 01:00:00
12   2012-01-01 01:05:00
13   2012-01-01 01:10:00
14   2012-01-01 01:15:00
15   2012-01-01 01:20:00
16   2012-01-01 01:25:00
17   2012-01-01 01:30:00
18   2012-01-01 01:35:00
19   2012-01-01 01:40:00
20   2012-01-01 01:45:00
21   2012-01-01 01:50:00
22   2012-01-01 01:55:00
23   2012-01-01 02:00:00
24   2012-01-01 02:05:00
25   2012-01-01 02:10:00
26   2012-01-01 02:15:00
27   2012-01-01 02:20:00
28   2012-01-01 02:25:00
29   2012-01-01 02:30:00
30   2012-01-01 02:35:00
31   2012-01-01 02:40:00
32   2012-01-01 02:45:00
33   2012-01-01 02:50:00
34   2012-01-01 02:55:00
35   2012-01-01 03:00:00
36   2012-01-01 03:05:00
37   2012-01-01 03:10:00
38   2012-01-01 03:15:00
39   2012-01-01 03:20:00
40   2012-01-01 03:25:00
41   2012-01-01 03:30:00
42   2012-01-01 03:35:00
43   2012-01-01 03:40:00
44   2012-01-01 03:45:00
45   2012-01-01 03:50:00
46   2012-01-01 03:55:00
47   2012-01-01 04:00:00
48   2012-01-01 04:05:00
49   2012-01-01 04:10:00
Name: dttm_utc, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now, what I want to achieve is this:

1. Basically, I would like to downsample the data down to every hour.
   I would like to sum and average out samples of the first hour, the second hour and so on i.e. I would like to sum and average all the values of rows numbered and 0-10 because they were collected in the first hour, next I would like to sum and average out data between rows 11 and 22 and so on. How can I achieve this using pandas commands?

Right now the sampling is done every 5 minutes if it changes to, let's say, every 2 or 10 minutes I would like my solution to still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data is a `Series` but your question is asking about summing and averaging values of rows so I'm unclear on what you're trying to sum and average without example data.

I think what you're interested in is `resampling` but this can only be done when the datetime column (`dttm_utc`) is in the index.

```
s = pd.Series(pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2012-01-01 00:05:00', periods=50, 
                   freq=pd.offsets.Minute(n=5)), name='dttm_utc')
s.reset_index().set_index('dttm_utc').resample(pd.offsets.Hour()).agg([np.sum, np.mean])
```

Gives you this... but it's a multi-index which makes things more complicated.

```
                    index      
                      sum  mean
dttm_utc                       
2012-01-01 00:00:00    55   5.0
2012-01-01 01:00:00   198  16.5
2012-01-01 02:00:00   342  28.5
2012-01-01 03:00:00   486  40.5
2012-01-01 04:00:00   144  48.0
```

If you wanted to remove the multi-index (multi-level columns), you could do this:

```
new_s = s.reset_index().set_index('dttm_utc').resample(pd.offsets.Hour()).agg([np.sum, np.mean])
new_s.columns = new_s.columns.droplevel(level=0)

                     sum  mean
dttm_utc                      
2012-01-01 00:00:00   55   5.0
2012-01-01 01:00:00  198  16.5
2012-01-01 02:00:00  342  28.5
2012-01-01 03:00:00  486  40.5
2012-01-01 04:00:00  144  48.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Jarad is absolutely right. I want to clarify his answer in relation to DataFrames (I guess you need to process data in DFs).

```
# dataset imitation with samples in column 'data1'
df = pd.DataFrame({'dttm_utc': pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=50, freq=pd.offsets.Minute(n=5))})
df['data1'] = np.random.randint(0, 500, len(df))

In [308]:df
Out[308]: 
                     data1
dttm_utc                  
2012-01-01 00:00:00    379
2012-01-01 00:05:00    387
2012-01-01 00:10:00    241
2012-01-01 00:15:00    197
...

# set column 'dttm_utc' as DatetimeIndex for downsampling to hours
In [309]: df.set_index('dttm_utc', inplace=True)

# hereinafter as from Jarad
In [310]: df.resample('H').agg([np.sum, np.mean])
Out[310]: 
                    data1            
                      sum        mean
dttm_utc                             
2012-01-01 00:00:00  3007  250.583333
2012-01-01 01:00:00  2832  236.000000
2012-01-01 02:00:00  3177  264.750000
2012-01-01 03:00:00  3376  281.333333
2012-01-01 04:00:00   402  201.000000
```