# Pandas: How to extract rows which are just within a time duration?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a data-frame like this.

```
                       value  estimated  \
dttm_timezone                                                             
2011-12-31 20:10:00  10.7891          0   
2011-12-31 20:15:00  11.2060          0   
2011-12-31 20:20:00  19.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:25:00  15.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:30:00  10.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:35:00  13.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:40:00  15.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:45:00  11.7891          0   
2011-12-31 20:50:00  10.9975          0   
2011-12-31 20:55:00  10.3933          0
```

By using the **dttm_timezone** column information, I would like to extract all the rows which are just within a **day** or a **week** or a **month**.

I have data of 1 year, so if I select day as the duration I should extract 365 days data separately, if I select month then I should extract a 12 months data separately.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: /@Haggar What have you tried?

Comment: Could you be more specific "extract all the rows which are just within a day"

Do you mean you would like to specificy a day and get out all the rows that occur in that day? Or do you mean you want to re-index the data so that its frequency is Daily? In the latter case, how do you want to aggregate the values? Take the maximum? The mean? et cetera

Comment: @MerIin: I know that the samples are collected every 5 minutes, so I have calculated how many rows it takes to make a day and a month. I'm worried that if the sampling time changes then it won't work, so I was just curious to know if there is any way to do it using pandas functions. I was thinking of using resample.

Comment: @michael_j_ward, I meant, I would like to extract samples of every day out for analysis. When I'm done analysing a day's data I would like to extract the next day's data, so on for all 365/366 days.

Comment: Can I use between_time somehow? I'm looking at it

Comment: @HaggarTheHorrible  Lets see some code?

Comment: @HaggarTheHorrible  What wrong with using the solution found here?  This is a dup.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266512/pandas-timeseries-data-how-to-select-rows-of-an-hour-or-a-day-or-a-minute

Comment: What is you objective? What do you want to do with the selected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tidx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2014-12-31', freq='H', name='dtime')

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(tidx)), tidx, ['value'])
```

You can limit to `'2010'` like this:

```
df['2010']
```

Or

```
df[df.index.year == 2010]
```

You can limit to a specific month by:

```
df['2010-04']
```

or all Aprils:

```
df[df.index.month == 4]
```

You can limit to a specific day:

```
df['2010-04-28']
```

all 1:00 pm's:

```
df[df.index.hour == 13]
```

range of dates:

```
df['2011':'2013']
```

or

```
df['2011-01-01':'2013-06-30']
```

There is ton of ways to do this:

```
df.loc[(df.index.month == 11) & (df.index.hour == 22)]
```

**link ---> [The list can go on and on.  Please read the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) <--- link**

Comment: @jezrael faster this time.  you are the quick one.